# docker can I mount os from another container

Tags: docker

I have been setting up a runtime with several images. I have been keeping them lean with one process and minimal os, based on debian (because I'm used to that).

However, I wonder why I need all these copies of the OS? Could I build one image with OS (to separate from host os) and then have other images mount relevant parts  (read-only or copy where necessary -- /etc/ ...)?

I tried googling for this pattern but didn't find it. Are there any pitfalls? Does docker need "something" present to be able to boot an image even before mounting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using `FROM debian` as the base of each of your images, you only have one copy of `debian`. That's the beauty of using a copy-on-write filesystem like AUFS or btrfs.

Comment: ok... does that also apply to runtime memory? (I guess there is no way to economize here no matter what...?)

Comment: I don't know a way to share runtime memory, sorry. There is probably a way, but at that point you're working against container isolation.

Comment: Sure -- thanks for the answer; in the original question I had forgotten how docker worked. Wrt to memory -- just curious as you are an expert -- never expected it to be shared.